# Beginner error with validating XML

Tags: xml

First post on the site. I am new to XML. Just started a few hours ago and have tried to create an XML file to import test data into a system. I have created the XML below but am getting an error when trying t validate it. Please forgive the dire layout. Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this and to understand it better? Thanks in advance.

The error is: error at line 2, column 11: no declaration found for the element 'Document'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<BkToCstmrStmt>
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>S0000001</MsgId>
</GrpHdr>
<Stmt>
<CreDtTm>2015-01-01</CreDtTm>
<Bal>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Cd>PRCD</Cd>
</CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="GBP">31213.54</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
<Dt>2015-01-01</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<Bal>
<Tp>
    <CdOrPrtry>
        <Cd>CLBD</Cd>
    </CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="GBP">31213.54</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
    <Dt>2015-01-01</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<Ntry>
<Amt Ccy="GBP">1000.00</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>DBIT</CdtDbtInd>
<BookgDt>
    <Dt>2015-01-01</Dt>
</BookgDt>
<NtryDtls>
    <TxDtls>
        <RmtInf>
            <Ustrd>Test File Description</Ustrd>
        </RmtInf>
    </TxDtls>
</NtryDtls>
<AddtlNtryInf>123456</AddtlNtryInf>
</Ntry>
</Stmt>
</BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I see you've commented an answer below - pleas use the `edit` link blow your Original Post (OP) to update your question with the correct XML, as it is in your code. We can't help you if we can't see the real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Document
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

The namespace declaration should be included in the root element.
You have closed the document element before the declaration.

Comment: Sorry that must have been a typo on my part when I added it to the question. In the xml document the declaration was included in the root element as you have detailed but it still displays the error message.

Comment: Okay no problem, are you validating against an XSD Schema? DTD? The document seems well formed, so I don't really get the problem.